# How prove there exist postive integer $n$ such $x_{n}>y_{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, sequences-and-series

> let two  positive sequence 
>   $\begin{cases}
> x_{n+2}=x_{n}+x^2_{n+1}\\
> y_{n+2}=y^2_{n}+y_{n+1}
> \end{cases}$
>   and $x_{1}>1,y_{1}>1,x_{2}>1,y_{2}>1$

show that: there exists $n$, such $x_{n}>y_{n}$

my idea: since

$$x_{n+2}-y_{n+2}=(x_{n}-y_{n+1})+(x^2_{n+1}-y^2_{n})$$
then follow I can't have idea.

maybe this problem can use contradiction

we Assume that 
$$x_{n}\le y_{n}\forall n\in N^{+}$$

A year ago, I have post this [How prove this $|x_{p}-y_{q}|>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433385/how-prove-this-x-p-y-q0)

But this two different problem,maybe can use same methods?

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction that $y_{n+2} < Cy_{n+1}^{3/2}$ for some positive constant $C$. Indeed, the $C$ is only needed in the base case. (Motivation: each term in the $y$ sequence is approximately the square of the term two terms earlier, once they become large; so maybe each term is like the $\sqrt2$ power of the previous term, and $\sqrt2<\frac32$.) Together with $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}^2$, it's easy to deduce the desired conclusion.